# how to analyze daily high and low temperatures between 3 different cities over a 30 day period?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, anova, repeated-measures

If I recorded the high and low temperatures (interval variables) in 3 different cities (categorical?) for 30 days and I wanted to examine whether the low and high temps for the cities were significantly different, what type of analysis would I run?

I am leaning towards a repeated measures anova. Possibly a factorial anova or a multiple regression as well.

Comment: The temperature data per city is auto-correlated, how much depends on the time between the measurements. You need to take that into account. In the specific case, I would not trust any result based on 30 subsequent days regardless of the method used. It also sounds like you define your hypothesis: are you trying to determine if the temperature is different in a specific months? Or are you talking about mean temperatures over a year?

Comment: Are you comparing cities or highs and lows? More generally, as @Erik implies, I think this needs much more on your data structure and precise goals to be easily answered.

Comment: @NickCox I'm comparing the highs and lows between the cities. see whether the low and high temperatures were significantly different between the three cities

Comment: @Erik just over a one month period.  Just 1 high temperature and 1 low temperature per day for each city over a 30 day period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use paired t-tests if the data are all collected on the same days.

You just need 3 paired t-tests for Highs and then 3 others for low. The reason is that we know that which day it is has an indirect effect on temperature. You can get an ANOVA to work, but I don't see a reason for it, as t-tests take seconds in Excel, or R or anything.

A regression isn't useful unless you want to extrapolate or interpolate missing data. If you do a regression, rather than using the date as an input, use the previous days temperature. I think, intuitively, that will work better for you (but I'm no meteorologist). It will also reduce you to only 29 data points.

Comment: what kind of ANOVA would this be if T tests were not an option.

Comment: Repeated Measures is definitely the one. The F-Statistic might not tell you what you want to know (unless you are hoping for null). It will only tell you if there is a difference, not between which two cities the difference lies.

Comment: How does this approach handle the autocorrelation issue?